# CGPA calculator

Tags: android, calculator, android-spinner, nan

Hi I am working on an Android Application which will help students to calculate there college CGPA. The App is 95% complete but i am having a small bug that i am note able to fix it.

The bug is that when i input all the values in the spinner and press the "CALCULATE" button on first time when i launch my app it does not produce proper result and show the "NaN" error.

According to my research it's ok to have "NaN" error when the input is "0/0" but the real problem is that even when i am not giving input 0/0 it is still giving NaN error on first time. When i change the input values on spinner and press "CALCULATE" again, Then it works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner,spinner2,spinner3,spinner4,spinner5,spinner6,spinner7,spinner8,spinner9,spinner10,spinner11,spinner12;
    TextView result;
    Button button1,button2;
    int a1=10,a2=10,a3=10,a4=10,a5=10,a6=10;
    int b1=0,b2=0,b3=0,b4=0,b5=0,b6=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1);

        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s1);
        spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s2);
        spinner3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s3);
        spinner4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s4);
        spinner5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s5);
        spinner6=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s6);
        spinner7=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s7);
        spinner8=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s8);
        spinner9=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s9);
        spinner10=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s10);
        spinner11=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s11);
        spinner12=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s12);




        String[] crdt={"0","1","2","3","4","5"};
        String[] grade={"O","A+","A","B+","B","C","P","F"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,crdt);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner5.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner7.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner9.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner11.setAdapter(adapter1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,grade);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner4.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner6.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner8.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner10.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner12.setAdapter(adapter2);

        result.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:a1=10; break;
                            case 1: a1=9;break;
                            case 2:a1=8;break;
                            case 3:a1=7;break;
                            case 4:a1=6;break;
                            case 5:a1=5;break;
                            case 6:a1=4;break;
                            case 7:a1=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                });
                spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:a2=10; break;
                            case 1: a2=9;break;
                            case 2:a2=8;break;
                            case 3:a2=7;break;
                            case 4:a2=6;break;
                            case 5:a2=5;break;
                            case 6:a2=4;break;
                            case 7:a2=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                }); spinner6.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:a3=10; break;
                            case 1: a3=9;break;
                            case 2:a3=8;break;
                            case 3:a3=7;break;
                            case 4:a3=6;break;
                            case 5:a3=5;break;
                            case 6:a3=4;break;
                            case 7:a3=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                }); spinner8.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0: a4=10;break;
                            case 1: a4=9;break;
                            case 2:a4=8;break;
                            case 3:a4=7;break;
                            case 4:a4=6;break;
                            case 5:a4=5;break;
                            case 6:a4=4;break;
                            case 7:a4=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                }); spinner10.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:a5=10; break;
                            case 1: a5=9;break;
                            case 2:a5=8;break;
                            case 3:a5=7;break;
                            case 4:a5=6;break;
                            case 5:a5=5;break;
                            case 6:a5=4;break;
                            case 7:a5=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                }); spinner12.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:a6=10; break;
                            case 1: a6=9;break;
                            case 2:a6=8;break;
                            case 3:a6=7;break;
                            case 4:a6=6;break;
                            case 5:a6=5;break;
                            case 6:a6=4;break;
                            case 7:a6=0;break;


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                    }
                });







            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b1=0; break;
                        case 1:b1=1;break;
                        case 2:b1=2;break;
                        case 3:b1=3;break;
                        case 4:b1=4;break;
                        case 5:b1=5;break;


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b2=0; break;
                        case 1:b2=1;break;
                        case 2:b2=2;break;
                        case 3:b2=3;break;
                        case 4:b2=4;break;
                        case 5:b2=5;break;


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b3=0; break;
                        case 1:b3=1;break;
                        case 2:b3=2;break;
                        case 3:b3=3;break;
                        case 4:b3=4;break;
                        case 5:b3=5;break;


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b4=0; break;
                        case 1:b4=1;break;
                        case 2:b4=2;break;
                        case 3:b4=3;break;
                        case 4:b4=4;break;
                        case 5:b4=5;break;


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });spinner9.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b5=0; break;
                        case 1:b5=1;break;
                        case 2:b5=2;break;
                        case 3:b5=3;break;
                        case 4:b5=4;break;
                        case 5:b5=5;break;


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });spinner11.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:b6=0; break;
                        case 1:b6=1;break;
                        case 2:b6=2;break;
                        case 3:b6=3;break;
                        case 4:b6=4;break;
                        case 5:b6=5;break;



                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


                }
            });


            double p=(a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3+a4*b4+a5*b5+a6*b6);
            double q=(b1+b2+b3+b4+b5+b6);


            if(p==0 && q==0)
            {
                result.setText("Result is: 0.0");
            }
            else {
                double r = (p / q);


                result.setText("Result is:" + r);
            }


        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            spinner.setSelection(0);
            spinner2.setSelection(0);
            spinner3.setSelection(0);
            spinner4.setSelection(0);
            spinner5.setSelection(0);
            spinner6.setSelection(0);
            spinner7.setSelection(0);
            spinner8.setSelection(0);
            spinner9.setSelection(0);
            spinner10.setSelection(0);
            spinner11.setSelection(0);
            spinner12.setSelection(0);
            result.setText("Result is: 0.0");


        }
    });
```

Comment: what is your button1 and button 2 .?

Comment: Reset is my button 2 and Calculate is my button 1

Comment: which line is throwing error?

Comment: No line is throwing error . It is that when i open the app and press Calculate for the first time then app does not calculate and throws the "NaN" in the textView and when i change the input in the spinner and press the calculate again..The app performs perfectly and does the right calculation

Comment: I added an answer, if that's wrong, add the logcat in your question please :) let me know if that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any errors in this question. The question is quite understandable. The problem is with your code I guess(a simple one).
If you can move all the

```
spinner.setItemSelectedListener({
//your codes
{
//switch case and all
}
});
```

before the **`button1`** Action, It should work.

Comment: You're a genius. My code gave the the right results. I am so grateful that you took the initiative to help me unlike those stupids who without understanding the problem downvoted my question. **A BIG Thanks!!**

Answer (score 0):

Problem should be that you are dividing by 0 ([and you can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)).

those lines don't have a 0 check for 2nd member

```
        if(p==0 && q==0)
        {
            result.setText("Result is: 0.0");
        }
        else {
            double r = (p / q); //here, q might be 0


            result.setText("Result is:" + r);
        }
```

so, first off decide what to do if q is 0, and do something like this:

```
if(p==0 && q==0)
{
    result.setText("Result is: 0.0");
}
 else {
    double r = 0.0;
    if(q == 0){
        r = p; // or whatever you want
    } else{
        r = p / q;
    }
    result.setText("Result is:" + r);
}
...
```

If I miss-understood the question, let me know!

Hope this helps

Comment: No ! thats not the solution

Comment: @courage99 ok, so improve your question adding the logcat and some more info, because understanding your code is pretty hard :)

Comment: @courage99 with my solution implemented, what is the output?

Comment: @courage99 in addition, using debugger, tell me the values of q and p in your first run. They are surely 0 and 0 imo

Comment: @courage99 just explain here, give the infos I asked you and it will be fixed